# How to access dictionary of dictionary in the interactive shell

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following data:

```
>>> {'Foo':{'LG.ip': {'NKCells': 3.4439999999999995, 'DendriticCells': 8.3127499999999994, 'Macrophages': 12.146249999999998}}}
```

But why accessing the following way gave error:

```
>>> dict['Foo']['LG.ip']['NKCells']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'Foo'
```

What's the right way to do it?

Comment: In your first line, you're not actually storing that dictionary in dict. Other than that, it should work; I just tried it to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interactive interpreter (only), you can use [the special identifier `_`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers), which stores the result of the last evaluation:

```
>>> {'Foo':{'LG.ip': {'NKCells': 3.4439999999999995, 'DendriticCells': 8.3127499999999994, 'Macrophages': 12.146249999999998}}}
{'Foo': {'LG.ip': {'NKCells': 3.4439999999999995, 'DendriticCells': 8.31275, 'Macrophages': 12.146249999999998}}}
>>> _['Foo']['LG.ip']['NKCells']
3.4439999999999995
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't save your dictionary to a variable! Hence you have not variable which keys you can access.

```
In [2]: a={'Foo':{'LG.ip': {'NKCells': 3.4439999999999995, 'DendriticCells': 8.3127499999999994, 'Macrophages': 12.146249999999998}}}

In [3]: a['Foo']['LG.ip']['NKCells']
Out[3]: 3.4439999999999995
```

As zhangxaochen said:
When you try `dict['key']` you are access the the keys in the most primitive Python dictionary which is the parent class for all dictionaries.

Comment: no, that would be another error `TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: Maybe he have used dict as a variable for a dictionary earlier. That would overshadow the builtin name, and give the error OP had.

Comment: @M4rtini, no, if you do like the OP `dict={'Foo'...}` you will not see the `TypeError` nor th `KeyError`.

Comment: That's not what i meant. He may previously have defined another dictionary with the name dict. It looks like he did this in some kind of interactive interpreter. So it could still be around. If you do `dict = {'old stuff':1}` and then forget to assign the new dictionary to a variable. You would get that key error.